# LDAP password expiry notification at login prompt

Tags: openldap

I have successfully configured OpenLDAP Server in rhel7.2.I have also implemented password policy as per URL https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2710021.

LDAP client server authentication is working fine.

I want whenever any LDAP user logs in to LDAP client,it should show how many days are left before password expiration(like we normally gets when a user logs into a machine)

For the same I have  modified my ldap password policy by "ldapmodify" command with "pwdExpireWarning" to 24 days.

When a user logs in to LDAP client,ldap user simply gets logged in with no message at loggin prompt.

code:

```
[root@LDAP Server]# ldapsearch -x -b cn=default,ou=policies,dc=domain,dc=com -H ldap://LDAP Server.domain.com
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=default,ou=policies,dc=domain,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# default, policies, domain.com
dn: cn=default,ou=policies,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: default
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: device
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 2592000
pwdInHistory: 4
pwdMinLength: 14
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
pwdLockoutDuration: 1800
pwdExpireWarning: 2073600
pwdCheckQuality: 2

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

When i logged in LDAP client:

```
[LDAP client]# su - ldapusr1
Last login: <Date> pts/0
[LDAP client]$
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because when a non-LDAP user logs in, it's the shadow attributes in the `/etc/shadow` file that control password expiry, whereas for an LDAP user the ppolicy overlay doesn't provide the same attributes.

You *can* apply the `shadowAccount` object class to each user and then provide those same attributes as found in the normal `/etc/shadow` file however you will have to maintain those manually, they won't be updated by the ppolicy overlay.